# Why this PyQt5 function called without argument?

Tags: python, pyqt5, signals-slots, qprocess

This function have state argument

```
def handle_state(self, state):
        states = {
            QProcess.NotRunning: 'Not running',
            QProcess.Starting: 'Starting',
            QProcess.Running: 'Running',
        }
        state_name = states[state]
        self.message(f"State changed: {state_name}")
```

But i dont understand why when connected to the stateChanged signal it was called without passing any argument but it is working?

```
self.p.stateChanged.connect(self.handle_state)
```

From the stateChanged documentation

```
PySide.QtCore.QProcess.stateChanged(state)
Parameters: state – PySide.QtCore.QProcess.ProcessState
```

The full code

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton, QPlainTextEdit,
                                QVBoxLayout, QWidget)
from PyQt5.QtCore import QProcess
import sys


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.p = None

        self.btn = QPushButton("Execute")
        self.btn.pressed.connect(self.start_process)
        self.text = QPlainTextEdit()
        self.text.setReadOnly(True)

        l = QVBoxLayout()
        l.addWidget(self.btn)
        l.addWidget(self.text)

        w = QWidget()
        w.setLayout(l)

        self.setCentralWidget(w)

    def message(self, s):
        self.text.appendPlainText(s)

    def start_process(self):
        if self.p is None:  # No process running.
            self.message("Executing process")
            self.p = QProcess()  # Keep a reference to the QProcess (e.g. on self) while it's running.
            self.p.readyReadStandardOutput.connect(self.handle_stdout)
            self.p.readyReadStandardError.connect(self.handle_stderr)
            self.p.stateChanged.connect(self.handle_state)
            self.p.finished.connect(self.process_finished)  # Clean up once complete.
            self.p.start("python3", ['dummy_script.py'])

    def handle_stderr(self):
        data = self.p.readAllStandardError()
        stderr = bytes(data).decode("utf8")
        self.message(stderr)

    def handle_stdout(self):
        data = self.p.readAllStandardOutput()
        stdout = bytes(data).decode("utf8")
        self.message(stdout)

    def handle_state(self, state):
        states = {
            QProcess.NotRunning: 'Not running',
            QProcess.Starting: 'Starting',
            QProcess.Running: 'Running',
        }
        state_name = states[state]
        self.message(f"State changed: {state_name}")

    def process_finished(self):
        self.message("Process finished.")
        self.p = None

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

w = MainWindow()
w.show()

app.exec_()
```

Comment: It is probably overloaded. Search 'polymorphism in the bar above and you'll find your answer.'

Comment: You say: "I dont understand why when connected to the stateChanged signal it was called without passing any argument". Are you referring to the connection line? `self.p.stateChanged.connect(self.handle_state)`

Comment: It's not called in your code, it's called by an instance of `QProcess`, and it supplies the necessary argument. Another note -- you refer to PySide documentation, but you're using PyQt5. These are _different_ Qt ports for Python.

Comment: @musicamante yes

Comment: @tromgy i know that the objects suply only the self argument but how can they suply other arguments?

Comment: @chilsaouimeknes as tromgy explained, you're not calling the function, the signal is. Signal connections work by providing a *reference* to a callable (in fact, `self.handle_state` has no parentheses there). Only when the signal will be emitted the connected function will then be called, using the arguments of the signal.

Comment: Qt Docs: [Signals & Slots](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html). PyQt Docs: [Support for Signals and Slots](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/signals_slots.html).